# How is a python script made into an executable?

Tags: python

I'm not asking how I should make my script into an executable; I'm aware of tools like py2exe.

I'm asking *how it happens*.

What is the process by which the interpreted python source is transformed into a compiled executable?

Comment: @ OK you have mentioned in question I commented on the basis of title sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really a compiled executable (as in "compiled to machine language"). [It's a bundle](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/FAQ) of your script's bytecode, the interpreter and all the libraries that your script requires to run. Your script is still interpreted.

Comment: Bytecode, as in the .pyc files?

Comment: @Aerovistae: Yes. Read the link above, it's all there.

Comment: Oh that link was almost invisible, I had to run my cursor over every word to find it, lol. Thanks.